# Angular: why $http GET params encrypted?

Tags: angularjs, http, http-get

I have a `GET` method but for some reason it sends encrypted `params`

```
var request = function (apiMethod, apiResponse) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var apiPath = getApiPath();

            apiPath = $rootScope.ROOT_URL + apiPath;

            var config = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: apiPath + apiMethod,
                params: 'email=myemail@gmail.com, timestamp_start=1432801800, timestamp_end=1432803600, organizer_email= myemail@gmail.com, cloudinary_rules=scale, meeting_name=123',
                //data: apiResponse,
                //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                //withCredentials: true,
                timeout: canceler.promise
            };
            $http.get(config).success(function (data) {

                $rootScope.showLoader = false;

                if (data.message === undefined) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                }

            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.showLoader = false;
                deferred.reject(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

However I get request as:

> [https://myapp.me/api.php/get_gadget_notes?0=e&1=m&10=a&100=d&101=a&102=c&103=o&104=r&105=p&106=@&107=g&108=m&109=a&11=c&110=i&111=l&112=.&113=c&114=o&115=m&116=,&117=+&118=c&119=l&12=o&120=o&121=u&122=d&123=i&124=n&125=a&126=r&127=y&128=*&129=r&13=r&130=u&131=l&132=e&133=s&134=%3D&135=s&136=c&137=a&138=l&139=e&14=p&140=,&141=+&142=m&143=e&144=e&145=t&146=i&147=n&148=g&149=*&15=@&150=n&151=a&152=m&153=e&154=%3D&155=1&156=2&157=3&16=g&17=m&18=a&19=i&2=a&20=l&21=.&22=c&23=o&24=m&25=,&26=+&27=t&28=i&29=m&3=i&30=e&31=s&32=t&33=a&34=m&35=p&36=*&37=s&38=t&39=a&4=l&40=r&41=t&42=%3D&43=1&44=4&45=3&46=2&47=8&48=0&49=1&5=%3D&50=8&51=0&52=0&53=,&54=+&55=t&56=i&57=m&58=e&59=s&6=l&60=t&61=a&62=m&63=p&64=*&65=e&66=n&67=d&68=%3D&69=1&7=a&70=4&71=3&72=2&73=8&74=0&75=3&76=6&77=0&78=0&79=,&8=n&80=+&81=o&82=r&83=g&84=a&85=n&86=i&87=z&88=e&89=r&9=d&90=_&91=e&92=m&93=a&94=i&95=l&96=%3D&97=l&98=a&99=n](https://myapp.me/api.php/get_gadget_notes?0=e&1=m&10=a&100=d&101=a&102=c&103=o&104=r&105=p&106=@&107=g&108=m&109=a&11=c&110=i&111=l&112=.&113=c&114=o&115=m&116=,&117=+&118=c&119=l&12=o&120=o&121=u&122=d&123=i&124=n&125=a&126=r&127=y&128=_&129=r&13=r&130=u&131=l&132=e&133=s&134=%3D&135=s&136=c&137=a&138=l&139=e&14=p&140=,&141=+&142=m&143=e&144=e&145=t&146=i&147=n&148=g&149=_&15=@&150=n&151=a&152=m&153=e&154=%3D&155=1&156=2&157=3&16=g&17=m&18=a&19=i&2=a&20=l&21=.&22=c&23=o&24=m&25=,&26=+&27=t&28=i&29=m&3=i&30=e&31=s&32=t&33=a&34=m&35=p&36=_&37=s&38=t&39=a&4=l&40=r&41=t&42=%3D&43=1&44=4&45=3&46=2&47=8&48=0&49=1&5=%3D&50=8&51=0&52=0&53=,&54=+&55=t&56=i&57=m&58=e&59=s&6=l&60=t&61=a&62=m&63=p&64=_&65=e&66=n&67=d&68=%3D&69=1&7=a&70=4&71=3&72=2&73=8&74=0&75=3&76=6&77=0&78=0&79=,&8=n&80=+&81=o&82=r&83=g&84=a&85=n&86=i&87=z&88=e&89=r&9=d&90=_&91=e&92=m&93=a&94=i&95=l&96=%3D&97=l&98=a&99=n)

How to send proper GET request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to give him an object instead of a string :

```
 var config = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: apiPath + apiMethod,
            params: {
               email:"myemail@gmail.com",
               timestamp_start:1432801800,
               timestamp_end:1432803600,
               [etc...]
            }
            //data: apiResponse,
            //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            //withCredentials: true,
            timeout: canceler.promise
        };
```

It was probably trying to URL encode the whole string as one parameter but not sure.

Hope it helped.

EDIT : Haha just re-read the get request.

It was actually taking the string as an array of params. so it was sending each letter as one param (look the params order : 0 : e - 1 : m - 2 : a (ema...) [etc...].